# create an echo server

Tags: python, sockets, echo-server

I am new to python and trying to code. I want to create simple echo server *ie whatever I input to the client will simply be echo back by the server* and if the client user press enter without writing anything then the server will disconnects. It may be very simple but I lacks logic here, any help??

here is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import socket
import sys

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) #create socket
s.bind(("0.0.0.0",12345))   #binding port
s.listen(1) #listening for only one client

print "I am listening..."

conn,addr=s.accept()    #accept the connection

conn.send("\nEnter your name.\n")

data = conn.recv(2048)
print "Client name is : ",data

conn.send("Now each word you typed will be echo back to you.\n")

while len(data)>0:
    data=conn.recv(2048)
    if data == '':
        sys.exit()
    else:   
        conn.send(data)
```

Comment: This works fine for me, at least in Python 2.x. What isn't working for you?

Comment: what i want is when client press enter key without enter anything then the server should disconnect. BTW i am using ubuntu as client and windows 8 as server.

Comment: Well, then simply check whether `data.strip() == ''` after receiving the name. I am still not sure what your problem is - if you can write `write` loops, an additional `if` shouldn't be the problem ;)

Comment: how silly was that!! thanks! data.strip() == '' works fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

The result will contain a newline, but you can simply call [str.strip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) to filter that out:

```
conn.send("\nEnter your name.\n")
data = conn.recv(2048)
if not data.strip():
    print('Please enter a name')
    return 1
print("Client name is : ", data)
```